# open and Save excel file in S3 using Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I have some problem with excel(xlsx) file.I want to just open and save operation using python code.I have tried with python but couldn't found

````
cursor = context.cursor()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket')

objects = bucket.objects.all()
for obj in objects:
  if obj.key.startswith('path/filename'):
    filename=obj.key
    openok=open(obj)
    readok = openok.readlines()
    readok.close()
    print ('file open and close sucessfully')```
````

Comment: What does this code do?

Comment: I want to just open and close the file in that s3 folder.

Comment: But _why_ do you wish to do this? If you explain your end-goal, we might be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: Actually we doing xlsx file load from s3 to redshift using matillion .Already we loaded multiple files,recently faced one difficult issue.Our matillion component colud not read the file.If we download and open and save the file its worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can't read/interact with files directly on s3 as far as I know.
I'd recommend downloading it locally, and then opening it. You can use the builtin tempfile module if you want to save it to a temporary path.

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    local_file_path = os.path.join(tmpdir, "tmpfile")
    bucket.download_file(obj.key, local_file_path)
    openok=open(local_file_path)
    readok = openok.readlines()
    readok.close()
```